# I have a problem with react navigation auth flow

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I have a login page and if not loged in it shows now the problem is when there is a token it shows the login page for a sec before going to the home page how can i stop it from doing so

I am useing useLayoutEffect and tryed gitting the token from friebase and from asyncStorge there allowes a deley

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);
  // const Token = useSelector((store) => store.userState.userToken);
  const isDarkTheme = useSelector((store) => store.themeState.Theme);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (mounted) {
        if (user) {
          setUserToken(JSON.stringify(user.uid));
        } else {
          setUserToken(null);
        }
      }
    });
    dispatch(getTheme());
    // dispatch(getToken());
    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [userToken]);

  const theme = isDarkTheme ? CustumDarkTheme : CustumDefaultTheme;

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Provider theme={theme}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
        {userToken ? (
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} /> }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigation} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Profile"
              component={Profile}
              options={({}) => ({
                gestureEnabled: true,
                cardOverlayEnabled: true,
                ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
                headerShown: false,
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="PatientDetails"
              component={PatientDetails}
              options={({}) => ({
                gestureEnabled: true,
                cardOverlayEnabled: true,
                ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
                headerShown: false,
              })}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Start" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} />
            <Stack.Screen name="LogIn" component={LogIn} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a loading state and show something until you get the token.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useEffect(true)

useEffect(()=>{if(userToken){setLoading(false)}},[userToken]

return (
    {loading?<LOADING INDICATION>:{userToken?ect}}
)
```